# Are there sparknotes for 5e book modules?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, rise-of-tiamat

Our group just finished Hoard of the Dragon Queen. I was finding it incredibly difficult to keep up with the plot (it just wouldn't stick in my brain). All I wanted, the entire time, was a dumbed-down version that I could just *read* so I could understand what was going on, what we had just done, without giving away key plot points, or hidden things that we had (undoubtedly) missed.

I really wanted a sparknotes version of HotDQ. We are going into Rise of Tiamat next (despite me buying our DM the book for Tomb of Annihilation).

I *really* want to know if there are any resources where I can find the basics of the module, without getting spoilers for it. Being able to read it would help me *so* much more than trying to figure out what's going on while our group fails to follow along with what our DM wants.

Comment: Clarification: you ask as a player, is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se. Take the [tour], it's a useful introduction to how things work around here. It looks like your question may be closed as off-topic as a "shopping" question (there'll be links describing why) but don't take it personally, that's just not something this site is build to handle. It should be an easy fix to get on-topic for this site though. Questions work best here when they focus on the actual problem you're facing, rather than focusing on one supposed solution to that problem.

Comment: If you can ask about your actual problem, instead of your solution, then we can certainly help with that. For example, your problem seems to be that your having trouble remembering key plot points and details, so maybe try asking how you can rectify that and let the solutions come to you rather than asking about *your* solution. I would also suggesting searching this site for other, similar questions as I'm sure there's plenty already out there that you might find an answer on.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I apologize for my failure on this.

Comment: Welcome to the stack. If you search this site, remember that we often write as experienced players/GMs, and not always care to properly use spoiler tags. As such, take care and have fun!

Comment: Perhaps I missed an edit which resulted in the current state, but I'm confused on why this question is closed as a "shopping" question. This is a request for resources for a very specific purpose: _plot overviews of 5e modules_. It isn't asking for recommendations on module to play or any other opinion-based questions.

Comment: @Newbie12345 the problem is that there's no criteria by which to judge answers, meaning that every answer would be equally (in)correct. It might *not* necessarily be a "shopping" question but if *"**any** resource"* is acceptable then one answer that provides the basics of the module becomes indistinguishable from another and that defeats the whole purpose of our voting system, making it too broad at least.